# How to convert System::IntPtr to char*

Tags: c++-cli

can any body tell How to convert System::IntPtr to char* in managed c++
this is my main function

```
int main(void) 
{
    String* strMessage = "Hello world";

    CManagedClass* pCManagedClass = new CManagedClass();//working
    pCManagedClass->ShowMessage(strMessage);//working


****above said error here***    
       char* szMessage = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(strMessage);
    CUnmanagedClass cUnmanagedClass; cUnmanagedClass.ShowMessageBox(szMessage);
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal((int)szMessage);

    return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

I'm not a huge C++/CLI programmer, but the following should work just fine.

```
IntPtr p = GetTheIntPtr();
char* pChar = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p.ToPointer());
```

The IntPtr class has a method called ToPointer which returns the address as a `void*` type.  That will be convertible to `char*` in C++/CLI.

**EDIT**

Verified this works on VS2008 and VS2015

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
char* szMessage = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(strMessage).ToPointer();
Marshal::FreeHGlobal((int)szMessage);
```

Use

```
marshal_context conversions.
const char* szMessage = conversions.marshal_as<const char*>(strMessage);
```

It cleans itself up, the magic of C++ RAII.

Comment: fyi, there's a typo in the second code block (not enough rep to change). `marshal_context conversions.` should be `marshal_context conversions;`

Answer (score 0):

**Attention!**

I want to add something to JaredPar answer.I don't know where your IntPtr is coming from but you should also use pin_ptr in order to prevent the garbage collector from messing up your memory. I did lot of CLR/Native inter op in the past and using pin_ptr is one of those things that I learnt to do in the hard way.

read the following:
[click me](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: The return value of `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi` is in unmanaged memory, and doesn't need to be pinned.